# Creating multidimensional array byt merging values

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an array of the type:

> array(4) {[0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=> string(1) "4"}

And I need to make a multidimensional array like this:

```
$data = array(
   array(
      $id => '1' ,
   ),
   array(
      '$id' => '2' 
   )
   ),
   array(
      '$id' => '3' 
   )
   ),
   array(
      '$id' => '4' 
   )
);
```

Where $id has constant value(let's say 6) and the value of the multidimensional array is the value from the first array.

Thanks

Leron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = array();

for($i=0;$i<count($firstArray);++$i) {
    $data[] = array('$id' => $firstArray[$i]);
}
```

Did you mean this?

**Edit:**

Sorry, I misread you question.

```
$data = array(); $id = '6';

for($i=0;$i<count($firstArray);++$i) {
    $data[] = array($id => $firstArray[$i]);
    // Or:
    // $data[] = array();
    // $data[$i][$id] = $firstArray[$i];
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Here is a testcode:

```
<?php

$firstArray = array("1", "2", "3", "4");

$data = array(); $id = '6';

for($i=0;$i<count($firstArray);++$i) {
    $data[] = array($id => $firstArray[$i]);
    // Or:
    // $data[] = array();
    // $data[$i][$id] = $firstArray[$i];
}

print_r($data);

?>
```

And the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [6] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [6] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [6] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [6] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: thanks, simple, and I hope this is what I need. Gonna try it ASAP and accept if it works

Comment: Yeah, just put it in my code, exactly what I need. Thanks! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want the same index and then it's child like this as you did :

```
$data = array(
   array(
      $id => '1' ,
   ),
   array(
      '$id' => '2' 
   )
   ),
   array(
      '$id' => '3' 
   )
   ),
   array(
      '$id' => '4' 
   )
);
```

Then, how can be the same index of the array every time for data mapping? If you want the data in one array then make something like

```
$data = array($id => array(
1,2,3,4 // IT WILL BE HOLDED BY YOUR $id
));
```

And, as you said for `Creating multidimensional array byt merging values` then go through `array_merge()`

Comment: I'm not sure what I should use for achieving the result I post in my question, the reason to want the same id is because i'm gonna use it for inserts using CodeIgniters active records and it requires array like this.

Comment: As you said that there is constant that holds the associative array. It depends what you're gonna do. If you want a multiple indexes having multiple values then do `$k = 0;
foreach($basearr as $key => $valuesArray) {
    $data[$k] = array($valuesArray); // $valuesArray would be 1,2,3,4,5. .....1
    $k++;
}`